# In $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i+b$, is the $b$ added to each $a_iX_i$ term, or is it added to the sum of those terms?

Tags: notation

I have a mathematical statement that I can interpretate in two different ways.

$$
X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i+b
$$

Should I read this as:

1. The summation of $a_{i}$ and $X_{i}$ and then add the constant $b$?
2. For each {i} add constant $b$ to the sum? In other words, if I took b out of the summation sign I would get $nb$

I am not aware of the governing rules regarding this statment. If I could get feedback on this, it would help me forward. Thanks

Comment: First one is right. You will get the second one if you have $
X=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i X_i+b)
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between
$X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i+b$
and
$X=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i X_i+b)$.
In first case, $b$ is added to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i X_i$, and in second - to each summand. For the first case, you can also write $X=b + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i$ to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The first option (since there are no round brackets). That's it.